# Are there languages in which plural classifiers co-occur with numerals?

Tags: syntax, grammatical-number, countability, classifiers, plurality

I'm aware that a number of classifer languages have what might be called "plural classifiers" which -- unlike "normal" classifier -- force a plural, count interpretation, instead of being ambiguous between a single interpretation with a mass-y quantification. That is, in the general case, we see things like:

**Bengali**:

```
Onek-Ta rasta  
many-Cl road   
"a lot of road" or "many roads"
```

**Mandarin**:

```
nei-ge  ren  
that-Cl person  
"that person" or "those people"
```

But, there are also "plural" classifiers for these languages that disambiguate, such as:

**Bengali**:

```
Onek-gulo rasta  
many-Cl.PL road  
"many roads"
```

**Mandarin**:

```
nei -xie   ren  
that-Cl.PL person  
"those people"
```

Cool. But, I also know that Bengali and Mandarin both disallow the "plural" classifier with numerals (and I think other weak quantifiers), so

**Bengali**:

```
*tin-gulo rasta
tin  -Ta rasta
three-Cl road
"three roads"
```

**Mandarin**:

```
*san-xie ren
san  -ge ren
three-Cl person  
"three people"
```

Are you familiar with a classifier language that has a "plural" classifier? If so, does it only occur on things that aren't numerals?

I'm aware of languages in which numerals co-occur with the stem of the noun and not the plural form (**cf.** Finnish *kissat* "cats" vs. *kolme kissaa* "three cats"), but this is obviously parameterized since in English we say "three cats", not "*three cat".

The reason why I ask this is I've been concerned about the fact that all(?) classifier languages seem to place a classifier with the word "one", so you get Mandarin Chinese:

```
*yi ren
yi-ge ren
one-Cl person
"a/one person"
```

Yet, there's no "plural" marker that occurs with the numeral "one" in languages that have a morphological singular/plural distinction. This should be surprising on the Doetjes/Borer-type story in which classifiers and number markers are all but the same thing, just morphophonemicized differently. Hence, I'm curious if the lack of co-occurrence with plural classifiers with numerals is a universal, or if that is parameterized in the same way as the Finnish/English distinction.

Comment: Are you sure it's "nei" for Mandarin? The demonstratives are "na", as far as I know.

Comment: There's discussion about this in the literature, actually. The "colloquiual" forms are often pronounced "nei", particularly when before a classifier. Some folks have claimed that this is due to a phonological raising process, and that "nei-ge" is actually morphologically complex -- na+yi+ge

Comment: Well, I don't know the colloquial language personally, so I can't actually reply on that. :) But then, you're treating the colloquial and not the standard language?

Comment: @dustinalfonso Have you looked at [Aikhenvald's book](http://ukcatalogue.oup.com/product/9780199264667.do)?

Answer (score 1):

I found a paper which treats about a language (well, two, but one is mainly treated, since it's the principal object of the dissertation) being in possess of the structure "number-Classifier". The Language is the *[Yucatec Maya Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yucatec_Maya_language)*.

The title is *"[The DP-adjoined plural in Yucatec Maya and the syntax of plural marking](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~lkbutler/butler2011_diss_chapter2.pdf)"*, a dissertation  by *Lindsay K. Butler* <sup>1</sup>.

I'll try to summarize the content through the paper, but I linked it anyway, both for a complete reference but also for attribution. If I misunderstood the paper or made some mistakes, please let me know by commenting under the answer. I don't want to leave mistakes floating in the internet.

Parts between «» (and italic) are directly pasted from the paper.

---

In many well-known Indo-European languages *«number is inflectional and obligatory»*. If we have a sentence with a determiner (such as an article), a noun and a verb, they must agree by number. Taking the same examples<sup>2</sup> from the paper:

> 1. Las muchachas están cantando. = Grammatical
> 2. *La muchachas están cantando. = Ungrammatical
> 3. *Las muchacha está cantando. = Ungrammatical

This is true for many languages, but it's not for the Yucatec Maya, and the paper states that *«plural marking in the noun phrase is not necessary for a noun to be interpreted as referring to a plurality»*.

Going forward<sup>3</sup>, we see that *«plural marking and classfiers co-occur even
within the same phrase, in Yucatec Maya»*:

```
(6) ka'a-túul    x-ch'úupal-o'ob
    two-CL.AN    FEM-girl-PL
    'two girls'

(7) óox-p'éel     ja'ab-o'ob
    three-CL.IN   year-PL
    `three years' (Blair and Vermont-Salas, 1967, 454)

(8) le óox-p'éel      siidra-o'ob-o'
    DEF three-CL.AN   cider-PL-DIST
   `the three ciders' (Andrade and Máas-Collí, 1999, 216)
```

<sup>CL.AN = Classifier Animated. Read footnote 4 about the examples 7 and 8.</sup>

Then, *«Plural marking and classiers have been shown to co-occur within the
same phrase in Persian as well (Gebhardt, 2009) (and Karimi, pc.). Examples
are shown in (9) and (10).»*

```
(9)  se      ta   gorbe-ha
     three   CL   cat-PL
     `three cats' (Gebhardt, 2009, 20)

(10) un   do    ta mænzel-ha
     DEM  two   CL house-PL
     `those two houses' (Gebhardt, 2009, 75)
```

---

<sup>**1**: Department of Linguistics, University of Arizona.</sup>
<sup>**2**: *"The typology of number markin"*, page 2.</sup>
<sup>**3**: *"Nominal denotation"*, chapter starts at page 4, examples in page 5.</sup>
<sup>**4**: Footnote taken from the paper (**"these examples"** refers to the examples #7, 8): *«These examples  are not partitives. In Yucatec the partitive has a denite determiner between the numeral-classier and noun, e.g. ka'a-tuul le x-ch'uupal-o'ob (two-cl.an def fem-girl-pl) `two of the girls.' I thank Scott AnderBois for this question.»*</sup>

Comment: I think this addresses your question, but let me know if I misunderstood your requests.

Comment: If I understand OP's question correctly, he/she is looking for cases where numerals are used with *purely plural* classifiers. So the question is whether túul, p'éel and ta can be used in the singular as well.